# How to support wildcard word expansion in my own shell implementation?

Tags: c, shell, wildcard, glob

I am writing my own implementation of a very simple shell, but I want to support wildcard word expansion. I have read an answer here on stackoverflow that suggested using [glob(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) to do the word expansion during tokenizing the command.

> One example of use is the following code, which simulates typing
>
> ```
> ls -l *.c ../*.c
> ```
>
> in the shell:
>
> ```
> glob_t globbuf;
>
> globbuf.gl_offs = 2;
> glob("*.c", GLOB_DOOFFS, NULL, &globbuf);
> glob("../*.c", GLOB_DOOFFS | GLOB_APPEND, NULL, &globbuf);
> globbuf.gl_pathv[0] = "ls";
> globbuf.gl_pathv[1] = "-l";
> execvp("ls", &globbuf.gl_pathv[0]);
> ```

Any idea how can I make this dynamic and work with commands that don't have wildcards as well as those who have only 1 or multiple wildcards?

Is glob(3) the best way to support wild card expansions for my shell or is there a better way?
Would regular expressions be a better alternative? I am trying to learn here so forgive me if I misunderstood something as I am relatively a beginner in this field.

Here is my tokenizer in case it would be helpful:

```
int build_args(char * cmd, char ** argv) {
char *token; 
token = strtok(cmd," ");
int i=0;
while(token!=NULL){
    argv[i]=token; 
    token = strtok(NULL," "); 
    i++; 
}
    argv[i]=NULL; 
    return i; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read [glob(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) - an interesting specification. Read also [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Play with [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) or [ltrace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) on some *existing* shell [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) (to understand what that shell actually does when you run it, and what [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) a shell is doing when *you* run it).

You can use [glob(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) (but see [fnmatch(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html) and [nftw(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html)...). You could also use [opendir(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) + [readdir(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) + [stat(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) + [closedir(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/closedir.3.html).

At last, [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) is a [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html). Why don't you download and study its source code? Or look into the code of [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) or inside the code of [zsh](https://zsh.org/) .... Both are [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source)!

Comment: How would strace help?

Comment: What's relevant in syscalls(2)?

Comment: Shells are using system calls.

Comment: Everything uses system calls. What's specifically relevant?

Comment: The OP will need to use system calls if he/she is writing a shell...

Comment: So if I decided to use glob(7) to perform the word expansion, should I perform this inside my tokenizer, right ? any guidance on how I can actually do this dynamically in order to work with different commands?

Comment: I recommend studying the source code of *existing* shells

Answer (score 1):

My expert opinion: `glob(3)` is not the best way, but it is the simplest way. If you are going to write a completely new shell, then perhaps it should have some features that some other shells don't - otherwise, why not write a shell, which could it has some extra wildcards not supported by `glob`. Then you cannot use `glob`.

The way how Unix shells work is that you can **always** glob in any command line, it doesn't depend on the commands. Therefore you can even do this:

```
% touch echo Hello world
% ls
echo  hello  world
% *
hello world
```

i.e. the glob operator expanded to `echo hello world` which was the command that was thereafter run.

But wildcard characters do not act as wildcards if they're enclosed in e.g. quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, but can you guide me into how can I use glob(3) to do the wildcard matching and expansion? 
I chose it because it is the simplest, I am not trying to add more features that are not already in other shells, I am just trying to learn how they internally work by building them myself.